# Is it possible to view Google reminders on Android without the Google Calendar app?

Tags: applications, calendar, reminders

I use the Google reminders a lot, and I find the integration with the Google Calendar app very useful. However, other than that, third-party calendar apps are generally better, in my view, than the Google one.
Is there a way to view (and edit) reminders with third party calendar apps?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you mean something completely other than event reminders: Of course it is possible. The Google Calendar app is nothing but a front-end: you can even delete its data, and your events (including reminders) will still be there.

On your Android device, events are managed by a "background service" and are stored with an app called "calendar storage", which is part of the Android OS. Every calendar app can (and most do) interface with that.

So just give it a try – you will find it works fine!

Comment: I'm not talking about *event* reminders, but rather Google reminders (I don't know if that has a different name), such as Inbox reminders, or what Google Now generates when you say "remind me to buy milk tomorrow morning"

Comment: Oh. No idea about what Google Now/Assistant creates as I don't use that (though I always thought it were calendar events). But talking about Inbox reminders, that seems to be something different and not tied to the calendar subsystem – so in that case I'm not sure how it works and whether 3rd party calendar apps would pick it up. If you (try and) find out, please let us know (and ping me: though I don't use it nor ever will, I'd like to know).

Comment: Inbox reminders (and also keep and google now reminders) all appear in the calendar on the web and also in the official google calendar app, and they are indeed different.

Comment: And they don't appear in any 3rd party calendar app? Have you tried?

Comment: I tried in the default Samsung and Asus apps and in Outlook for Android.  None of them have that option.

Comment: Looks like those reminders are [handled by the stock alarm clock](https://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m7/278365-where-reminders-kept.html), so you'd need a calendar app that also deals with stock alarms. Not that I've heard of any, but I never paid attention to that aspect so I might simply have missed it. So would "check your stock alarm clock" answer your question?

Comment: That link is ancient.  Reminders have changed a lot since them.  I wouldn't place much stock in them.

Comment: The page says 8/2016, so I didn't feel it that ancient. But now you write it, I took a closer look: no idea where they took that date from, all posts are indeed from 2013, apologies. No further ideas then.